# How to set the number of Touch ID retry attempts?

Tags: ios, touch-id

How do I set the number of retry attempts for Touch ID? I am presenting the alert with evaluatePolicy, but don't see any way to set the number of retries...

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt you can. And you **should not** be able to it.

Reasons you should not be able to lower the amount of possible attempts: it would just annoy the user, if he misplaces his finger and then cant authenticate. Basically it just be a bad design choice of you to reduce the number of tries.

Reasons you should not be able to increase the amount of possible attempts: the limit is there to remove the possibility to somewhat brute-force your way in, e.g. trying every finger of another ones hand, etc. If you would allow an app to increase the number of attempts it would just be a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

While the property is not in the [Apple documentation for LAContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html) as of today, the header file does have some information. Here's what it says:

```
/// Allows setting the limit for the number of failures during biometric authentication.
///
/// @discussion When the specified limit is exceeded, evaluation of LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
///             evaluation will fail with LAErrorAuthenticationFailed. By default this property is nil and
///             the biometric authentication fails after 3 wrong attempts.
///
/// @warning Please note that setting this property with high values does not prevent biometry lockout after 5
///          wrong attempts.
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *maxBiometryFailures NS_AVAILABLE(10_10, 8_1);
```

When I set `authContext.maxBiometryFailures = @1;` in a sample app, I get the "Application retry limit exceeded" error after 1 failure, as advertised. Looks like it was introduced in iOS 8.1.

Comment: nice find, but this doesn't seem to work with much consistency.. sometimes it retries the number of times i specify, sometimes its fewer..

Answer (score 1):

@Ajay Beniwal is right, the ability to change the number of attempts, `maxBiometryFailures`, was deprecated in iOS 9.0

From Apple's documentation of LAContext:

[image]